# PL/SQL Complex Type for SOAP request in Oracle

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, plsql, wsdl

I have to create SOAP request from PL/SQL and, thanks to [this](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i.php), it's working for simple requests. Now I'm standing in front of bigger challenge, because I have to pass specified data object as parameter. It includes simple types, other complex objects and enums. I have WSDL file with web service specification.

How to do this? Create Object Type in PL/SQL by my own ? Or, I hope, there is a tool which can create this Object Type for me from WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - in `soap_api` there is method `add_complex_parameter(p_request IN OUT NOCOPY t_request, p_xml IN VARCHAR2)` which allows us to add xml fragment created by ourselves. So only one thing to do is to generate xml containing complex object.

Comment: How you generated xml containing complex objects as we can have n no of elements in a single complex object